# Loading local libaries in jekyll (Liquid template library + ruby bundler)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler

My question is: ***How do I load local libaries in ruby and with bundler + jekyll?***

I'm trying to load a bunch of local libraries.
For example: project_root/_plugins/fileexists.rb

I've tried following https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/ but that solution assumes you have a library that can be installed from the global Gem repository.

The plugins I'm trying to load are here https://github.com/nicnocquee/appolo/tree/master/_plugins

The error I'm getting when  doing 'bundle exec jekyll serve':

```
Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have fileexists or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- fileexists' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
```

To complicate the matter, I'm using the Liquid template library. (Though this shouldnt be a Liquid problem because I get the error when doing bundle exec jekyll serve. I think..)

```
{% file_exists {{ fb_img_default }} %}
```

The code for the template is here:
https://github.com/nicnocquee/appolo/blob/master/_includes/head.html#L25

My _config.yml file for jekyll: https://pastebin.com/SphuLcVt
The Gemfile: https://pastebin.com/3ptcBx5m

Thanks in advance for ideas about how to proceed!

**Library version**

bundle  --version
Bundler version 1.16.0

ruby --version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

gem --version
2.5.2

Comment: I've updated my question, but short answer - I'm using the template language Liquid to try use the library code: {% file_exists {{ fb_img_default }} %}

Comment: According to the page you linked, you don't have to do __anything__. "In your site source root, make a `_plugins` directory. Place your plugins here. Any file ending in *.rb inside this directory will be loaded before Jekyll generates your site." If your thing is not recognized in liquid templates, must be it's not a proper plugin (doesn't register itself correcly or something)

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev your idea about "According to the page you linked, you don't have to do anything" lead me in the right direction. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.

I removed:

```
plugins:
 - fileexists
```

From _config.yml

And removed:

```
gem 'fileexists', :path => '/home/test/xxx.github.io/_plugins/fileexists'
gem 'github-pages'
```

from Gemfile

The clue that github-pages packet was the problem: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5990#issuecomment-308231021

***Short answer:***
"No custom plugins will load when using github-pages because of their whitelist."

Comment: You might like [Jekyll without plugins](http://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugins/).